# Java program for count of number of words in table

Tags: java

I have written Java code that finds the no.of words in the table.

It is working within the loop, but the value becomes 0 once it exits the loop.

Please help me to get correct value.

```
int f=0;
int fc=0;
Statement sta4=connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs4=sta4.executeQuery("select * from db1");
while(rs4.next())
{
    word[f]=rs4.getString(1).replace("$", "");
    System.out.println(" sentece ="+word[f]);
    fc= countWords(word[f]);
    System.out.println("The sentence has "+ fc + " words");
    f++;
}
System.out.println(" count  =" + fc);
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Please provide the console output what you are getting.

Comment: perhaps it should be `fc += ...` instead of `fc = ...`?

Comment: I assume you meant `fc +=`...

Answer (score 0):

```
int f=0;
int fc=0;
Statement sta4=connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs4=sta4.executeQuery("select * from db1");
while(rs4.next())
{
    word[f]=rs4.getString(1).replace("$", "");
    System.out.println(" sentece ="+word[f]);
    int fcTemp= countWords(word[f]);
    System.out.println("The sentence has "+ fcTemp + " words");
    fc += fcTemp;
    f++;
}
System.out.println(" count  =" + fc);
```

Use this. you werent adding up `fc`

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon, more so ones that don't format their code. Please explain the problem and the solution, maybe explain how `a += b` relates to `a = a + b`. There is no need to "correct" the code - leave the OP to work that out. But if you do decide to paste blocks of code **format them**.